# How do I make ion-menu-button larger in md(Android) mode?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I changed the font-size of my ion-menu-button (hamburger button) using the following CSS code.

```
ion-menu-button  {
  font-size: 31px !important;
}
```

The above code seems to work on my app in ios mode. (See attached screenshot)
[image: Screenshot of Ionic App in ios mode]

But that was not the case when I tried running the app on md mode(Android). The hamburger button is still small even and the CSS code doesn't have an impact  (See attached screenshot)
[image: Screenshot of Ionic App in md mode(Android)]

Some fixes I tried include adding a CSS with .md class to target the hamburger button specifically but it didn't work.

I tried fixing my problem by applying this code from Stack Overflow: [How do I make ion-menu-button larger?](https://stackoverflow.com)

After applying the fix above, the hamburger button now has the right size but the toolbar appears to become larger and I don't want my toolbar to look larger that's why I reverted the fix and was hoping someone could help me solve my issue. (See attached screenshot)

[image: Screenshot of Ionic App after applying code fix]

Comment: I think you need to move this ```font-size``` style on the host to make an easy customization of your button *from* ```ion-menu-button{font-size: 31px !important;}``` *to* ```:host{font-size: 31px;}```

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Newbee. I tried it already but my hamburger button just appear to be smaller while the icons from the right appeared to become bigger.

Comment: Maybe you need a class. Try add class then add it to host*(ex)*```:host(.menu_btn){font-size: 31px;}``` Or make the icon to be larged ```<ion-icon size="large"></ion-icon>```

Comment: @Newbee, thank you for the above tips. I appreciate that. I still have the same issue unfortunately. As for the latter tip, the tag is <ion-menu-button> but it didn't work even after adding the 'size' attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help. There is limited code, so I couldn't check what really causing the problem is. If you could provide some of your could or make an playground, It could be help. Then this *ion-icon* should inside your *ion button*. This is what it looks like. ```<ion-menu-button><ion-icon size="large"></ion-icon></ion-menu-button>```. But i said, maybe this couldn't help so until ypu provide some of your data, maybe I could help in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your feedbacks. I was able to find a solution to my problem by adding class="ion-no-padding ion-no-margin" to my . I'm not exactly sure how it work but I'm satisfied with this workaround. My final code is:

```
<ion-menu-button auto-hide="false" class="ion-no-padding ion-no-margin"></ion-menu-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using the zoom property:

```
ion-menu-button  {
 zoom: 1.8;
}
```